# Swift upload audio file to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi I try to upload a m4a file to Firebase Storage but always got error " Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." 
ResponseBody=Can not finalize upload.  Current size is 38298.  Expected final size is 34554.

This is my code :

```
func uploadSound(localFile: URL) {
    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    let imagesRef = storageRef.child("upload")
    let fileName = "/" + self.deviceID + ".m4a"
   let uploadTask = spaceRef.putFile(localFile, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL()
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate for the help..thanks

Comment: Hey Voyager did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

you have to send metadata too and the file as data, try this. for swift5

```
let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "audio/m4a"
    let riversRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("message_voice").child("\(self.getDate()).m4a")
    do {
        let audioData = try Data(contentsOf: recorder.url)
        riversRef.putData(audioData, metadata: metadata){ (data, error) in
            if error == nil{
                debugPrint("se guardo el audio")
                riversRef.downloadURL {url, error in
                    guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
                    debugPrint("el url descargado", downloadURL)
                }
            }
            else {
                if let error = error?.localizedDescription{
                    debugPrint("error al cargar imagen", error)
                }
                else {
                    debugPrint("error de codigo")
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You create the following variables, both of which are unused:

```
let imagesRef = storageRef.child("upload")
let fileName = "/" + self.deviceID + ".m4a"
```

When you upload you are calling:

```
// where is `spaceRef`?
spaceRef.putFile(localFile, metadata: nil)
```

As a suggestion, maybe try:

```
let newFileRef = imagesRef.child(fileName)
let uploadTask = newFileRef.putFile(localFile, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Bradley, i think my storage security has no issue because i i can upload image with data fromat.

Comment: still the same, I tried to change with Data but seems the file is corrupt, success to upload but can't play